# UPDATE STATEMENT :[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate;

Tags: sql, join, select, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I get this error Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate 
if I use OR operator in my update statement.I tried IN operator also but getting same error,

My original update query is

```
UPDATE db.table1 
SET    col1 = table2.col1, 
       col2 = table2.col2 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  ( col3 = table2.col3 
          OR col3 = table2.col4 ) 
       AND col5 = 'some string';
```

I tried using IN operator but getting same error

```
UPDATE db.table1 
SET    col1 = table2.col1, 
       col2 = table2.col2 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  col3 IN ( table2.col3, table2.col4 ) 
       AND col5 = 'some string';
```

what will be the alternative of OR in Redshift update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a Redshift limitation - basically it would only accept an intersection of equality conditions in the join conditions of an update (the `OR` operator fails to meet the *intersection* part, and `IN` won't trick the database).

For this query, I think that it might just be simpler to split it into two statements - this is less efficient, but at least it is possible:

```
UPDATE db.table1 
SET    col1 = table2.col1, 
       col2 = table2.col2 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  col3 = table2.col3 
       AND col5 = 'some string';

    UPDATE db.table1 
SET    col1 = table2.col1, 
       col2 = table2.col2 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  col3 = table2.col4 
       AND col5 = 'some string';
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you qualify the column references?

```
UPDATE db.table1 
    SET col1 = table2.col1, 
        col2 = table2.col2 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.col3 IN ( table2.col3, table2.col4 ) AND
          ?.col5 = 'some string';
```

The `?` is because I don't know what table that comes from.

Comment: ? is target table table1 like table1.col5 = 'some string'; but still it wont work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

---

I got another option from my colleague, Thanks @Swarup

```
UPDATE db.table1 
SET    col1 = res.col1, 
       col2 = res.col2 
FROM   ( 
          SELECT table2.col1, 
                 table2.col2, 
                 table2.col3 AS col_common 
          FROM   table2 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT table2.col1, 
                 table2.col2, 
                 table2.col4 AS col_common 
          FROM   table2 )res 
WHERE  table1.col3=res.col_common AND table1.col5 = 'some string';
```